# Multiple commands produce FirebaseAnalytics.framework build error in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-analytics

After upgrading to the latest version of React Native (0.70.3) and updating all npm packages including the Firebase dependencies to version 16.1.1, my iOS app fails to build with the below error. Others who experienced similar errors said to look at the Copy Bundle Resources section in Xcode and remove any duplicates from there, but my list doesn't have any duplicates so I'm at a loss as to how to fix this...

[image]

```
note: Building targets in dependency order
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/justintoth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Marriage365-cvaqfonbgyahhfgjedajduowtwdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FirebaseAnalytics/AdIdSupport/FirebaseAnalytics.framework'
    note: That command depends on command in Target 'FirebaseAnalytics' (project 'Pods'): script phase “[CP] Copy XCFrameworks”
    note: That command depends on command in Target 'FirebaseAnalytics.default-WithoutAdIdSupport' (project 'Pods'): script phase “[CP] Copy XCFrameworks”
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/justintoth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Marriage365-cvaqfonbgyahhfgjedajduowtwdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FirebaseAnalytics/AdIdSupport/FirebaseAnalytics.framework' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy XCFrameworks /Users/justintoth/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Marriage365-cvaqfonbgyahhfgjedajduowtwdf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseAnalytics.default-WithoutAdIdSupport.build/Script-46EB2E00033070.sh (in target 'FirebaseAnalytics.default-WithoutAdIdSupport' from project 'Pods')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved it with these steps :

- Choose whether you want to use Firebase with ou without Support
- In my case, I didn't this support, so I've modified the podfile with

  - Replace the line pod 'Firebase/Analytics' with pod 'Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport'
  - Add this line before in your podfile : $RNFirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport = true
- build with pod install

It fixed my problem